# Nuget package with NET Standard 1.X

Tags: c#, asp.net, portable-class-library, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

As a proof-of-concept, I would like to create a Nuget package that consists of a single assembly. This assembly is compiled using the brand new **.NET Standard 1.X profile**. My idea is to make it usable not only by .NET Core, but also from .NET 4.6.1 (full framework), or even older versions, but I don't know how.

For the moment, I created a `nuspec` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>

    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <description>MyPackage</description>

    <version>X.X.X.X</version>
    <authors>JMN</authors>
    <owners>JMN</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0</licenseUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>

  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\MyLib.dll" target="lib\netstandard1.X\MyLib.dll" />
  </files>

</package>
```

The problem is that, when adding the package to a project that targets .NET Framework 4.6.1, it says this message (output window)

> Could not install package 'MyLib X.X.X.X'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

What should I do to make my nuget package usable for both Frameworks (at least both .NET Standard 1.X and .NET Framework 4.6.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need your own nuspec at all.

Simply create an RC 2 project.json and then use `dotnet pack` to generate a NuGet package.

http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/libraries/libraries-with-cli.html

You cannot expect older versions of .NET Framework to support such package, as .NET Standard 1.5 is too high a version.

Comment: "You can expect older versions of .NET Framework to support such package" Are you missing a negative?

Comment: How do I create a RC2 project? And where do I write that command? I have VS 2015 Update 2, without any add-in. Can you please add more info? Thanks!

Comment: @SuperJMN http://dot.net you have to install .NET Core RC2 bits and then you can create new projects.